# How to make matrix unitary again?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, gram-schmidt

I know QR decomposition of matrix A, with mxn, where m > n. I want to find a QR decomposition of matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} A \\ a \end{bmatrix}$$ where a - vector 1xn.
My idea is:
$$\begin{bmatrix} QR \\ aR^{-1}R \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} Q \\ aR^{-1}\end{bmatrix}R = \hat{Q}R$$
And it works fine R is stil upper-triangle. But $\hat{Q}$ is not unitary. What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a computer or by hand? If you're using a computer, you could use the rank-1 update algorithm for the QR decomposition. See [this Matlab method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qrupdate.html) for instance